# python3 variable expansion "a"*x to add empty elements in a list

Tags: variables, csv, python-3.x, expansion

How can I use python3 variable expansion to add empty elements into a list.

```
>>> "a"*5  
'aaaaa'
```

This initialises a list with 3 elements.

```
l = ['']  
>>> l  
['']  
>>> l.append('')  
>>> l.append('')  
>>> l  
['', '', '']
```

When I try to add 5 empty elements I get just one.

```
>>> l=['' * 5]  
>>> l  
['']
```

I am writing this list into a csv, I want a cheap way to added empty columns, elements in a row. Where I build the row as elements in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a matter of semantics.  Where I did the multiplication.

```
>>> l = [''] * 5  
>>> l  
['', '', '', '', '']
```

or

```
>>> l=[]  
>>> l.extend([''] * 5)  
>>> l  
['', '', '', '', '']
```